# Is $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}|_{P}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}|_P}{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}|_P}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question

Suppose a function :

$$y = f(t), x = g(t)$$

I know that :

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}}{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}}$$

But I want to confirm if for a given point $P$ on curve, is it correct to distribute like below or not ?
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}|_{P}=\left.\frac{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}}{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}}\right\vert _P=
\frac{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}|_P}{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}|_P}$$

Comment: consider $x = y = t^2$ at $t = 0$

Comment: Yes. This is just what a quotient of functions means.

Comment: To be clear, since my comment seems to contradict Claude's, your "I know that" is not always true (or rather, not always defined), but where it *is* true, the "evaluate at P operator" distributes.

Comment: @Claude If we assume that $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$ is not zero and everything is differentiable and defined in a suitable domain. Will it be now ?

Comment: @preferred_anon Thanks. Can you write an answer showing a proof ?

Comment: Yes, it follows directly from multi variable calculus, for $ x=\cos t, y= \sin t$ for constant $t$ the line slope is $\tan t$, slope of tangent at P is its negative reciprocal $ \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}.$

Comment: @Narasimham Unfortunately I haven't studied multivariable calculus.